# Running two classes in Java concurrently

Tags: java, audio, synchronization, synchronized

I have been struggling with this problem for two hours but still couldn't found a solution.

Actually I am new to Java, and not at all familiar to Java's `synchronized`. I don't even know if I need to use `synchronized` to achieve what I need.

This is the structure of my package.

```
----------------------------
|----recorder.java
|          -------captureScreen.java
|          -------captureSound.java
                     |----start();
                     |----stop();
```

I am building a screen recorder for my web app. I have made the screen capturer and a separate class that can record audio too. But I am not able to make them work concurrently.

I have

```
captureSound sound = new captureSound();
```

When I start sound recording, it waits till I stop the recorder. **Here** is where my problem is. What I wish to do is after doing `sound.start()` my program should go down to execute other statements of `recorder.java`, i.e. `recorder.java` shouldn't wait for execution of `captureSound()`. But it stops. How do I make them both run concurrently? So that I can later do `sound.stop()` from my `recorder.java` itself.

Comment: Take some time to [educate yourself.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) It sounds like you should be using multithreading or some other concurrent-execution construct.

Comment: Tip: use Threads: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html

Comment: @MattBall I did see that. What I understood is that on declaring `start()` and `stop()` as synchronized, `recorder.java` shouldn't have waited for `start()` to finish. I got this from somewhere where a color example was given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## What Synchronized Does

the `synchronized` key word means a few things

1. The section surrounded by `synchronized` cannot have multiple threads running in areas synchronized by the same object, in other words you are **guaranteed synchronous access** that is if `isTrue` is `false` in a synchronized section, in the current content, unless acted on by the thread currently in the synchronized section it will remain that value.
2. It also means that the operations will not be reordered for optimization purposes
3. When used as a method descriptor, that is having  a method with the following sort of style

   ```
   public synchronized void doWork(Object parameter)
   {
       /*do stuff*/
   }
   ```

   translates to the following:

   ```
   public synchronized void doWork(Object parameter)
   { 
       synchronized(this)
       { 
           /*do stuff*/ 
       } 
   }
   ```

### Synchronized does not magically start threads

You need to start the threads yourself, I can't tell you how many times I find people thinking that just because you make a method or a synchronized block magically spins up a thread without them doing any work, this is a way to **control access to critical sections of code**.

### Creating a new Thread

There are a few ways to do this, but the best way (IMO) is to use a class that implements Runnable and have your thread consume it

```
Recorder recordIn= new Recorder();
Scanner scanIn= new Scanner();
Thread threadRecord = new Thread(new Runnable() {
```

```
    private final Recorder target = recordIn;
    @Override
    public void run() {
    //do stuff in here
    }
```

});
Thread threadScan = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        private final Recorder targetsRecorder = recordIn;
        private final Scanner target = scanIn;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //do stuff here
    }

});

threadRecords.start();
threadScan.start();

### Making sure your code works

Now you need to make sure that your synchronized code works. Depending on what you are trying to do you will need to do be concerned about different things. One commonly used example would be having a thread wait on one thread, you do this by waiting on the object handle. For example I want to scan the recorder every time movement is noticed.
Also, please remember I am doing this on the fly without an IDE, and I am assuming only these two threads are in operation acting on the objects

```
Thread threadRecord = new Thread(new Runnable() {
```

```
    private final Recorder target = recordIn;
    private final Scanner scanr= scanIn;     
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //if movement is noticed compared to the last frame save 
        recordIn.startRecording();
        while(true){
            synchronized(target ){
                while(target.hasMore()){

                   synchronized(scanr)
                   {
                       while(!target.currentImage().equals(scanr.getLatestImage())
                       {
                           target.recordMore();    
                           scanr.wait();
                       }
                   }
                 }
            }
        }
     }
}
```

});
Thread threadScan = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        private final Recorder targetsRecorder = recordIn;
        private final Scanner target = scanIn;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //do stuff here
            synchronized(target){
                target.wait();
                while(true)
                {
                    while(!targetsRecorder.doneRecording() && targetsRecorder.currentImage().equals(scanIn.getLastImage()))
                        target.wait();

```
                if(targetsRecorder.doneRecording())
                    return;

                scanIn.scanCurrentImage(targetsRecorder);
             }
        }       
}
```

}
});

threadScan.start();
threadRecord.start();

### Doing this with event listners

As you said you are doing this with event listeners, the concept is the same just spin up a new thread in the event listner

```
//inside of your listner
public void someRecordEventHappened(RecordEvent event){
    new Thread(new Runnable
    {
         private final RecordEvent eventDate = event;
         @Override
         public void run()
         {
             //do stuff asynchronously

         }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Is there no other way to go with this? I am opening the recording window and having play/pause event listeners everything in the `recorder.java` file. This means I will have to change too much if I use this way (having two different threads for screen recorder and audio recorder). i.e. will have to make a new class with all play/pause functions.:(

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you mean you want them running concurrently. This means using two+ threads.  I suggest you take timestamps for the captures so you can tie them to the audio recording.

Comment: @OptimusPrime Have one thread capturing the audio while the other thread captures the screen.  This way they are done concurrently and the audio doesn't need to stop.

Comment: @OptimusPrime you wanted to say `asynchronously` ;-)

Comment: @OptimusPrime synchronously means in step together, but in Java it is too easily confused with `synchronized` which means can be used by multiple threads but typically one at a time.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Is there no other way to go with this? I am opening the recording window and having play/pause event listeners everything in the `recorder.java` file. This means I will have to change too much if I use this way (having two different threads for screen recorder and audio recorder). i.e. will have to make a new class with all play/pause functions.:(

Comment: @OptimusPrime Adding classes and threads in Java is pretty simple, I can't imagine anything much simpler which would work reliably.